# problems in importing data into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

In a excel file there are two columns: Name and Time

When I want to import in database by default it takes the time column as varchar type.

And after importing the excel it was not converted into date format.

```
     select distinct cast([time] as datetime) FROM [table1]
```

It shows an error

```
 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

In the time column the value is like 9/26/2014 and after importing it insert 41908 in the database

What will be the solution?

N.B: there are Null values in the Time column in excel. Before importing I manually format the time cell into date format but still did not working.

Answer (score 0):

Always you can ensure to set the date format as you want with

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
```

just in case that the date format is in another format

but you have to take care of Null values, so what i propose is to check if the value is null if so, do nothing but if not, convert to date.....

like this.

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
select distinct case when [time] is null then 0 else cast([time] as datetime) end case from [table1]
```

you always can remplace de cero (0) to whatever you want.

Comment: On Excel you have to make the time columns as text

Go to "Format Cells" > "Date" > "Text" > "OK"

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two things, 
First, check the column datatype in SQL table whether it is Datetime or varchar.
Second, check your excel column whether it is formatted as date or not.

Now, to insert your date column in SQL Table

Check the below steps:

1) Use the formula, =Text(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy") for excel with date column. DO COPY PASTE SPECIAL to remove formula from the column before importing the data.

2)

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
select distinct Cast(Cast([time] as varchar(11)) as Datetime) FROM [table1]
```

Note: In case of NULL Values in excel is date column showing text "NULL" or is it empty?